# Disable Button After Click for 60 Seconds Even If Browser Refreshes Using Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, sugar.js

I have been searching, with tons of trial and error, yet to find a solution for this issue. I have found solutions but nothing that I have been successful at implementing.

I am using Meteor and want to create an input/button that is disabled for 60 seconds once clicked. I can make this part happen but my biggest issue is that refreshing the browser makes the button clickable again.

Is there any way to tie the timer to the user id? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was reading about Date.now(); and Sugar JS, but was not able to make them work for my application.

Comment: Use `sessionStorage` variables to make it happen.

Comment: Now that you bring this up, and the user below brought up localstorage... both do not last through browser/tab closing. I just found this out through reading. Is there a solution that would last through browser restarts?

Comment: `sessionStorage` lasts until the tab is closed and `localStorage` lasts even if you close the browser.

Comment: Ohh I see, I must have misread. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the html localstorage.
eg:

```
WHILE CLICKED BUTTON SET THIS.
     localStorage.setItem('status', 1);

While 60 sec complete then apply
     localStorage.setItem('status', 0);
```

and check everytime when button click weather localstorage is 0 or 1.

```
if 0 submit else return false. And to get localstorage value use as
localStorage.getItem('status');
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try and implement this right now. I will upvote when I get a few more reputation points.

Comment: @Jon Potts You don't need to upvote. Since you asked the question accept the answer by clicking on the tick.